# This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Picker

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I added a view to my app that I open from a button and can't find what I'm doing wrong.

I triple checked that dataSource & delegate are connected to File's Owner

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<HelpViewController 0xab58980> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Picker.'
```

The code in my viewcontroller.h

```
@interface LanguageSelectionViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UILabel *label;
    IBOutlet UIPickerView *Picker;
    NSArray *PickerData;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *Picker;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray *PickerData;
@end
```

Anyone got a solution or a tip in the right direction?

Comment: Yup, looks like you have connected an outlet to a property called "Picker" and then deleted the property in the code. You also need to remove the connection from the Storyboard file/Xib file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The class is not key value coding-compliant for the key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932397/the-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key)

Comment: Also see these search results: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=NSUnknownKeyException+class+is+not+key+value+coding-compliant+for+the+key . Please always do a some searching on error messages before posting a question.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your storyboard click the helpviewcontroller (the whole thing so you have a blue outline around the view) now with the utility toolbar (toolbar on the right) click the arrow (the right most icon) you should see a ! mark on one of the connections. Delete that and it should work.